# Generating Static HTML Dashboard Using Plotly Python API - Controlling Element Layout

Tags: python-3.x, data-visualization, plotly

I'm looking at the gorgeous and powerful Plotly Python API with the goal of generating a static html dashboard.

This raises two questions:

1. For generating html, I see the following [example](https://plot.ly/python/html-reports/). It appears the charts are embedded via a URL. Does this URL embedding implementation still apply since plotly has gone open source? Are there now other methods for sending plotly plots to static html?
2. How does one control the layout of the plots/dashboard elements? In Bokeh, for example we could do something like:

   `bar  = Bar(<define bar plot>)
   line  = Line(<define line plot>)
   donut = Donut(<define donut chart>)
   bar_line_panel = hplot(bar, line)
   final_layout = vplot(bar_line_panel, donut)
   output_file('foo.html')
   show(final_layout)`

The rendered html file would contain the line and bar plots next to each other above the donut chart. Is there similar functionality in plotly, or are templates and html/css wrangling required to specify layout for plot elements like in this [example](https://plot.ly/python/dashboard/)?

Thank you for your time, very much looking forward to creating some interactive visualizations in Plotly!